# What is the purpose of having multiple SSIDs

Tags: wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will segmenting wi-fi SSIDs limit the spread of viruses, trojans and the like?](https://serverfault.com/questions/275124/will-segmenting-wi-fi-ssids-limit-the-spread-of-viruses-trojans-and-the-like)

Seeing I am new to the world to networking and need to set up a router, what is the purpose of having multiple SSIDs. Not sure if this qualifies as a separate question (and if it does let me know and I'll post it as a separate question), what is the purpose of having multiple antennas on the router/modem?

Comment: This is pretty much a dup of your previous question: http://serverfault.com/questions/275124/will-segmenting-wi-fi-ssids-limit-the-spread-of-viruses-trojans-and-the-like  SSIDs have **nothing** to do with routers except for the fact that consumer-grade access points are often also routers.  In any case, this is off-topic, it's not a professional sysadmin question.

Comment: @Ward- I disagree as the question in my previous post was whether SSIDs provided any form of security. Secondly, it is a professional sysadmin question as I need to implement a secure wireless network as part of my role as junior administrator.

Comment: @Ward - Also when you say they have nothing to do with routers, can you please clarify? Please do not ignore/disqualify the fact that SMEs often use consumer-grade routers/modems.

Comment: At the very least, you need to be clearer: you say you're setting up a router, but your question is only about SSIDs, which is really the access point functionality of a wireless router, not the routing capability.  The answer you accepted to your previous question pretty much covers why you might want to have different SSIDs.  And answers to your antenna question are easily googled.

Comment: @Ward - That is correct I am setting up a router that allows me to set up multiple SSIDs as well. I apologize if what I was referring to was not about routing however the question does not answer what multiple SSIDs do? For example I understand they can separate networks however is that all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a wireless router broadcast multiple SSIDs means that it creates multiple networks. This is useful, for example, for creating a password-protected internal network and a public guest network. The router separates traffic so that people on the guest network can't interact with people on the private one.

As far as I know, multiple antennas are just for increasing range.